# SAS removing duplicate values with blanks

Tags: duplicates, sas

I need to remove duplicate values with the one with blanks from SAS: Example data below

| Match | forename | surname | dob | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| purple | John | will | 220985 | 1 |
|  | John | will | 220985 | 1 |
| green | donny | aman | 210784 | 2 |
|  | tyrone | smith | 010295 | 3 |
| Green | tyrone | smith | 010295 | 3 |

I would like to remove the match with blank spaces that have the same id. Some remove duplicates that have a blank using the id column

Answer (score 0):

First, sort it by `id match`. This will ensure missing values are first within each `id` group and the value you want is the last in the group:

```
proc sort data=have;
    by id match;
run;
```

```
Match   forename    surname dob     id
        John        will    220985  1
purple  John        will    220985  1 <----- value we want
green   donny       aman    210784  2 <----- value we want
        tyrone      smith   10295   3
Green   tyrone      smith   10295   3 <----- value we want
```

Since the non-missing value is always the last one in the group, we can use by-group processing on `id` and use `last.id` to only output on the last value within each ID group.

```
data want;
    set have;
    by id match;
    if(last.id);
run;
```

This "if without then" says "Do not continue unless it's the last value in the ID group." Since `output` is implied at the `run` boundary, SAS will not output a row unless it's the last ID in the group. In other words, only output for each value that we want.

```
Match   forename    surname dob     id
purple  John        will    220985  1
green   donny       aman    210784  2
Green   tyrone      smith   10295   3
```